# cisco ASA - redirect a port on external interface to an internal server port

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

Using a cisco ASA device with an external IP of 200.20.20.20 (interface OUTSIDE) and an internal subnet of 10.1.1.1/24 (interface INSIDE), how can I configure the ASA so that all traffic to a specific port on the external interface gets directed to an internal server (and the response is returned)

For example, if an external user connects to 200.20.20.20:5000 I want it redirected to 10.1.1.27:8080;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TO get this working you will need to setup a static nat, and add to the access-list to allow the traffic once.  (NAT happens before access-list: [Details of Order of operations](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk361/technologies_tech_note09186a0080133ddd.shtml))

#### Static NAT

Static NAT's on cisco have always been weird (for me at least).  Basic thing to remember is *(HIGH,LOW) LOW, HIGH* for this command.

> static (inside,outside) tcp
>   200.20.20.20 5000 10.1.1.27 8080 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0

#### ACLs

This acl will need to be applied to what ever you have named your access-list attached to OUTSIDE interface.  (Change: *outside_acl* )

> access-list outside_acl extended permit tcp any host 10.1.1.27 eq 8080

#### Disclaimer

Sorry I don't have my test ASA in front of me, but this should be very close.

Comment: spot-on; I just set the Static NAT, confirmed that packets were then being rejected by the ACLs, and tweaked the ACL.

Comment: Glad I could help - Have a good day/night